# SAS Error Handling in Windows Batch

Tags: sas

I have a scheduled SAS program in Windows, e.g.

`sas.exe -nosplash -icon -sysin "myprogram.sas"`

This process will hang if there's an "Out of Resources" error (e.g. no disk space), prompting for user input (Retry, Cancel, etc.). As it's a batch job, there is no user to give that input.

Is there a SAS system option which prevents the prompt for user input so it can be dealt with in the code itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `-noterminal`?

Extract from [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000203915.htm):

> If NOTERMINAL is specified, dialog boxes are not displayed.

Comment: Will test tomorrow, but no doubt that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using the option

```
-batch
```

Since you are running in batch mode, also consider using the option

```
-errorabend
```

The best option is

```
-get_more_resources ;)
```

If the program is the cause to the resource error you have another question to ask!

Comment: I don't want it to abend though, and `-batch` only simulates certain batch settings in interactive mode.